# How to read many items from a configuration file, using std ::

Tags: c++, std

I created a function called `LoadPaths()`, which creates a map of values read from the `texture.cfg` file.

The `texture.cfg` file is as follows:

```
plyIdle assets/player_idle.png 6 56 56
plyWalk assets/player_walk.png 10 56 56
plyRun assets/player_run.png 8 56 56
plyAtch assets/player_attack.png 8 56 56
plyShd assets/player_shield_defence.png 3 56 56
plyCrch assets/player_crouch.png 5 56 56
plyDth assets/player_death.png 12 56 56
plyJmp assets/player_jump.png 6 56 56
plyFlu assets/player_fly_up.png 2 56 56
plyFlg assets/player_falling.png 6 56 56
plyLng assets/player_landing.png 2 56 56
```

In this way, I get as an answer:

```
assets/player_run.png
```

What I would like now is to obtain for each animation path, its values indicated in the `texture.cfg` file, that is for:

```
assets / player_run.png
8 56 56
```

which represent respectively: number of frames, width and height of the frame.

How should I always use `std::...` that allows me a good performance in execution?

Below is the `LoadPaths()` function that creates the map of values read from the `texture.cfg` file:

```cpp
#include "GetPath.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

void LoadPaths(const std::string& l_pathFile, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>&    m_paths)
{
    std::string percorso = GetWorkingDirectory();

    std::ifstream paths;

    //Map animations player: IDanimation, pathAnimation
    m_paths = { {"", ""} };

    paths.open(percorso + l_pathFile);
    if (paths.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(paths, line))
        {
            std::stringstream keystream(line);
            std::string pathName;
            std::string path;
            int frame;
            int width;
            int height;
            keystream >> pathName;
            keystream >> path;
            keystream >> frame;
            keystream >> width;
            keystream >> height;
            m_paths.emplace(pathName, path);
        }

        paths.close();

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "! Failed loading the path file: " << percorso + "texture.cfg"
                          << std::endl;

        return;
    }
}
```

In `main()`, I have the following:

```cpp
#include "GetPath.h"
#include "LoadPaths.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    //Map animations player: IDanimation, pathAnimation
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m_paths = { {"", ""} };

    LoadPaths("texture.cfg", m_paths);

    auto path = m_paths.find("plyRun");
    path != m_paths.end() ? path->second : "";

    std::cout << path->second << "\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, the version must be C++17, otherwise it does not compile.

The extracted data, which are 3 integers, I want to put them in 3 `int` variables to be used later, together with the `path->second` that I put in the main.

Can you help me?

Comment: If you want optimal performance, you shouldn't encode the data as a text file. If the input is just a small file like this, any optimization is very likely premature optimization and won't result in noticable differences on any modern hardware...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to put them in 3 `int` variables to be used later

Then I suggest you should define a `struct` to hold them (and the image path), and then you can put instances of that `struct` into your `std::unordered_map` instead of a `std::string`.  For example:

```cpp
// PathInfo.h

#ifndef PATHINFO_H
#define PATHINFO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Path
{
    std::string path;
    int frame;
    int width;
    int height;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, Path &p)
{
    in >> p.path;
    in >> p.frame;
    in >> p.width;
    in >> p.height;
    return in;
}

#endif
```

```cpp
#include "GetPath.h"
#include "PathInfo.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

void LoadPaths(const std::string& l_pathFile, std::unordered_map<std::string, Path>& m_paths)
{
    std::string percorso = GetWorkingDirectory();

    //Map animations player: IDanimation, pathAnimation
    m_paths.clear();

    std::ifstream paths(percorso + l_pathFile);
    if (paths.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(paths, line))
        {
            std::istringstream keystream(line);
            std::string pathName;
            Path path;
            if (keystream >> pathName >> path)
                m_paths.emplace(pathName, path);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "! Failed loading the path file: " << percorso + l_pathFile << std::endl;
    }
}
```

```cpp
#include "GetPath.h"
#include "LoadPaths.h"
#include "PathInfo.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    //Map animations player: IDanimation, pathAnimation
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Path> m_paths;

    LoadPaths("texture.cfg", m_paths);

    auto path = m_paths.find("plyRun");
    if (path != m_paths.end())
    {
        std::cout << path->second.path << "\n"; 
        std::cout << path->second.frame << ' ' << path->second.width << ' ' << path->second.height << "\n"; 
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau for the advice and the correct code.